# Grabbing the href attribute of an A element

Tags: php, html, dom

Trying to find the links on a page.

my regex is:

```
/<a\s[^>]*href=(\"\'??)([^\"\' >]*?)[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/
```

but seems to fail at

```
<a title="this" href="that">what?</a>
```

How would I change my regex to deal with href not placed first in the a tag?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

[Reliable Regex for HTML are difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491). Here is how to do it with [DOM](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    echo $dom->saveHtml($node), PHP_EOL;
}
```

The above would find and output the ["outerHTML"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/php-domdocument-outerhtml-for-element/5404962#5404962) of all `A` elements in the `$html` string.

To **get** all the text values of the node, you do

```
echo $node->nodeValue;
```

To **check** if the `href` attribute exists you can do

```
echo $node->hasAttribute( 'href' );
```

To **get** the `href` attribute you'd do

```
echo $node->getAttribute( 'href' );
```

To **change** the `href` attribute you'd do

```
$node->setAttribute('href', 'something else');
```

To **remove** the `href` attribute you'd do

```
$node->removeAttribute('href');
```

You can also query for the `href` attribute directly with [XPath](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//a/@href');
foreach($nodes as $href) {
    echo $href->nodeValue;                       // echo current attribute value
    $href->nodeValue = 'new value';              // set new attribute value
    $href->parentNode->removeAttribute('href');  // remove attribute
}
```

Also see:

- [Best methods to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)
- [DOMDocument in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979836/noob-question-about-domdocument-in-php/4983721#4983721)

*On a sidenote: I am sure this is a duplicate and you can [find the answer somewhere in here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=find+all+href+attributes+dom+php)*

Comment: Reliable regex for parsing HTML are inherently impossible even since HTML is not a regular language.

Answer (score 19):

I agree with Gordon, you MUST use an HTML parser to parse HTML. But if you really want a regex you can try this one :

```
/^<a.*?href=(["\'])(.*?)\1.*$/
```

This matches `<a` at the begining of the string, followed by any number of any char (non greedy) `.*?` then `href=` followed by the link surrounded by either `"` or `'`

```
$str = '<a title="this" href="that">what?</a>';
preg_match('/^<a.*?href=(["\'])(.*?)\1.*$/', $str, $m);
var_dump($m);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(37) "<a title="this" href="that">what?</a>"
  [1]=>
  string(1) """
  [2]=>
  string(4) "that"
}
```

Comment: just for info: if we search in a text containing many a elements than expression (.*?) is wrong

Answer (score 4):

The pattern you want to look for would be the link anchor pattern, like (something):

```
$regex_pattern = "/<a href=\"(.*)\">(.*)<\/a>/";
```

Comment: What if the anchor has more attributes?

Answer (score 3):

why don't you just match

```
"<a.*?href\s*=\s*['"](.*?)['"]"

<?php

$str = '<a title="this" href="that">what?</a>';

$res = array();

preg_match_all("/<a.*?href\s*=\s*['\"](.*?)['\"]/", $str, $res);

var_dump($res);

?>
```

then

```
$ php test.php
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "<a title="this" href="that""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "that"
  }
}
```

which works. I've just removed the first capture braces.

Comment: i recomend to use `preg_match_all("/<a.*?href\s*=\s*['\"](.*?)['\"]/", $str, $res, PREG_SET_ORDER);` in order to catch correctly all href values in using `foreach($res as $key => $val){echo $val[1]}`

Answer (score 3):

For the one who still not get the solutions very easy and fast using SimpleXML

```
$a = new SimpleXMLElement('<a href="www.something.com">Click here</a>');
echo $a['href']; // will echo www.something.com
```

Its working for me

Answer (score 2):

Quick test: `<a\s+[^>]*href=(\"\'??)([^\1]+)(?:\1)>(.*)<\/a>` seems to do the trick, with the 1st match being " or ', the second the 'href' value 'that', and the third the 'what?'.

The reason I left the first match of "/' in there is that you can use it to backreference it later for the closing "/' so it's the same.

See live example on: http://www.rubular.com/r/jsKyK2b6do

Comment: @bergin please specify, what doesn't work? I get the exact value from the href in your test HTML. What are you expecting that this doesn't do? I see you use a different site for testing, there I also get the 'href' value succesfully from your example. http://www.myregextester.com/?r=d966dd6b

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but if you're trying to validate the link then look at PHP's filter_var()

If you really need to use a regular expression then check out this tool, it may help:
http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

Answer (score 2):

Using your regex, I modified it a bit to suit your need.

`<a.*?href=("|')(.*?)("|').*?>(.*)<\/a>`

I personally suggest you use a [HTML Parser](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

EDIT: Tested

Comment: using myregextester.com - sorry, doesnt find the links

Comment: it says: NO MATCHES. CHECK FOR DELIMITER COLLISION.

Comment: Can you please tell me the text to match? I use: `<a title="this" href="that">what?</a>`

Comment: My guess regarding this misunderstanding is that bergin didn't add pattern delimiters to Ruel's answer which does not use pattern delimiters.  Without pattern delimiters, the regex engine will assume `<` is the starting delimiter and `>` is the ending delimiter (of course those characters appear in the pattern, so you have "collisions".

Answer (score 0):

The following is working for me and returns both `href` and `value` of the anchor tag.

```
preg_match_all("'\<a.*?href=\"(.*?)\".*?\>(.*?)\<\/a\>'si", $html, $match);
if($match) {
    foreach($match[0] as $k => $e) {
        $urls[] = array(
            'anchor'    =>  $e,
            'href'      =>  $match[1][$k],
            'value'     =>  $match[2][$k]
        );
    }
}
```

The multidimensional array called `$urls` contains now associative sub-arrays that are easy to use.

Comment: I find single quotes to be a suboptimal choice for pattern delimiters -- it is so often used for actual quoting of strings that my eye didn't immediately register it as the delimiter.  The most common delimiter is probably `/`, but since your pattern used `/`, I might recommend `~`.  Because the delimiters are not `/`, you don't need to escape the `/` in your pattern.  You also don't need to escaping `<` or `>` because they have no special meaning to the regex engine.

Comment: like this `"\<a.*?href=\"(.*?)\".*?>(.*?)</a>\si"` @mickmackusa ?

Comment: No.  You mustn't use backslashes as delimiters.  Go for forward slashes.

Answer (score -1):

preg_match_all("/(]*>)(.*?)(</a)/", $contents, $impmatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

It is tested and it fetch all a tag from any html code.