# php regex to get string inside href tag

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I need a regex that will give me the string inside an href tag and inside the quotes also.

For example i need to extract theurltoget.com in the following:

```
<a href="theurltoget.com">URL</a>
```

Additionally, I only want the base url part.  I.e. from `http://www.mydomain.com/page.html` i only want `http://www.mydomain.com/`

Comment: General Consensus: Don't use Regular Expressions to parse HTML.

Comment: Ok, how can i get the href tag then using php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php is all you need.

Comment: Your data doesn't even contain a scheme. `href`'s may not always contain the scheme and domain.

Comment: duplicate of [Regular expression for grabbing the href attribute of an A element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/regular-expression-for-grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: @AndyLester Hi Andy, the site is htmlparsing.com (with /php is a 404).

Comment: @zeuf I need to fix that.  http://htmlparsing.com/php.html and http://htmlparsing.com/php should be the same.

Answer (score 23):

Dont use regex for this.  You can use xpath and built in php functions to get what you want:

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($myHtml);
    $list = $xml->xpath("//@href");

    $preparedUrls = array();
    foreach($list as $item) {
        $item = parse_url($item);
        $preparedUrls[] = $item['scheme'] . '://' .  $item['host'] . '/';
    }
    print_r($preparedUrls);
```

Comment: can provide a topic related $myHtml sample string please c:

Comment: How to check html is invaild. something like user enter the html `<div>` as `div>`

Comment: This is the most elegant way for extract the attributes from a HTML document.

Answer (score 15):

```
$html = '<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/page.html">URL</a>';

$url = preg_match('/<a href="(.+)">/', $html, $match);

$info = parse_url($match[1]);

echo $info['scheme'].'://'.$info['host']; // http://www.mydomain.com
```

Comment: This will not work when there are more attributes in the tag. E.g. href="http://www.mydomain.com/page.html" class="blue" rel=even". This returns [path] => /page.html" class="blue" rel=even"

Comment: Additionally: yes, this will work if you're only looking for the base url part (the 2nd part of the question by @David)! If you are looking for the entire url between the href, use another regex (I will try posting this in an answer below).

Answer (score 9):

this expression will handle 3 options:

1. no quotes
2. double quotes
3. single quotes

> '/href=["\']?([^"\'>]+)["\']?/'

Comment: I have a case where this expression works, except when double quotes urls contain single quotes (like how the google maps urls do). Right now, your regex stops at the first single quote (even if the url is surrounded by double quotes)

Answer (score 8):

Use the answer by @Alec if you're only looking for **the base url part** (the 2nd part of the question by @David)!

```
$html = '<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/page.html" class="myclass" rel="myrel">URL</a>';
$url = preg_match('/<a href="(.+)">/', $html, $match);
$info = parse_url($match[1]);
```

This will give you:

```
$info
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.mydomain.com
    [path] => /page.html" class="myclass" rel="myrel
)
```

So you can use `$href = $info["scheme"] . "://" . $info["host"]`
Which gives you:

```
// http://www.mydomain.com
```

---

When you are looking for **the entire url** between the href, You should be using another regex, for instance the regex provided by @user2520237.

```
$html = '<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/page.html" class="myclass" rel="myrel">URL</a>';
$url = preg_match('/href=["\']?([^"\'>]+)["\']?/', $html, $match);
$info = parse_url($match[1]);
```

this will give you:

```
$info
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.mydomain.com
    [path] => /page.html
)
```

Now you can use `$href = $info["scheme"] . "://" . $info["host"] . $info["path"];`
Which gives you:

```
// http://www.mydomain.com/page.html
```

Answer (score 4):

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/parse-links/

> Let's start with the simplest case - a well formatted link with no extra attributes:

```
/<a href=\"([^\"]*)\">(.*)<\/a>/iU
```

Comment: `/U` modifier fixed my problem. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This won't work if there are other attributes in the `<a>` element.

Answer (score 4):

For all href values replacement:

```
function replaceHref($html, $replaceStr)
{
    $match = array();
    $url   = preg_match_all('/<a [^>]*href="(.+)"/', $html, $match);

    if(count($match))
    {
        for($j=0; $j<count($match); $j++)
        {
            $html = str_replace($match[1][$j], $replaceStr.urlencode($match[1][$j]), $html);
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
$replaceStr  = "http://affilate.domain.com?cam=1&url=";
$replaceHtml = replaceHref($html, $replaceStr);

echo $replaceHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will handle the case where there are no quotes around the URL.

```
/<a [^>]*href="?([^">]+)"?>/
```

But seriously, [do not parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use DOM or a proper parsing library.

Comment: i am afraid of DOM a little bit, i believe that REGEX could save your life in many cases ...

Comment: No quotes around the URL ... is that even syntactically correct?

Answer (score -1):

```
/href="(https?://[^/]*)/
```

I think you should be able to handle the rest.

Answer (score -2):

Because Positive and Negative Lookbehind are cool

```
/(?<=href=\").+(?=\")/
```

It will match only what you want, without quotation marks

> Array (
>       [0] => theurltoget.com )