# PHP: find text between href='' tag

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php regex to get string inside href tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001328/php-regex-to-get-string-inside-href-tag)

I have a text file where there are multiple occurrences of href tag.

I wish to get the content of these

```
href='...'
```

and print it to screen.

How can I achieve that? The main problem is writing a correct regex.

Comment: Sorry I've just noticed there's an identic question out there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001328/php-regex-to-get-string-inside-href-tag?rq=1

Comment: It just doesn't end, does it?[Die, Cthulu, Die](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) _Parse the HTML_

Comment: I've voted to close my own question :)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem grabbing hrefs in a given html file isn't really "parsing html", and if you know what the HTMl is going to look like (for example a flat list of links), it might be better to use regexes than a full-blown parser.

Comment: @Cygal: in rare cases, you could be right, but regex's will only take you so far, parsing the string is just so much more reliable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$pageData = file_get_contents('your.txt');
if(preg_match_all('/<a\s+href=["\']([^"\']+)["\']/i', $pageData, $links, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER))
    $all_hrefs = array_unique($links[1]);
```

Now you have all unique hrefs in `$all_href`;

if you want to display them:

```
foreach($all_href as $href)
{
echo $href;
}
```

Comment: +1 for quote checking and case insensitive

Answer (score -1):

```
preg_match_all('|<a href="(.+)">|', $file_content, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Not tested, but should work