# PHP DomDocument editing all links

Tags: php, domdocument

I am using the following code to grab html from another page and place it into my php page:

```
$doc = new DomDocument;

// We need to validate our document before refering to the id
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
$doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents('{URL IS HERE}'));
$content = $doc->getElementById('form2');

echo $doc->SaveHTML($content);
```

I want to change all instances of `<a href="/somepath/file.htm">` so that I can prepend to it the actual domain instead.  How can I do this?

So, it would need to change them to:  `<a href="http://mydomain.com/somepath/file.htm">` instead.

Comment: If I were you, I will avoid using `DomDocument` and directly use regex to find out the links & edit it.

Comment: how come?  Everywhere I go on Stack Overflow, they say you should use `DomDocument` for this.  Can you give me an example of how to do this with a regex?

Comment: You create extra objects for just find & replace tasks. Extra parsing time & memory spent. Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001328/php-regex-to-get-string-inside-href-tag

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try something like:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument(); 
$xml->loadHTMLFile($url); 
foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) { 
   $oldLink = $link->getAttribute("href");
   $link->setAttribute('href', "http://mydomain.com/" . $oldLink);
}
echo $xml->saveHtml();
```

Comment: But the `href` is different for each link, so I would just need to prepend the domain to it.  Would it just be:  `$link->setAttribute('href', "http://mydomain.com/" + $link->getAttribute('href'));`  ??

Comment: Ok, great, but I gotta get the `$content` not the whole document.  Anyways, I figured it out from your answer.  So, you got it.  Thanks :)