# Replace href with a different value

Tags: php, html

I have some PHP code which grabs a website's HTML code, then echos it to the screen. I'm looking for a way to scan the HTML, and then replace all href values with another value. For example, I have "http://somepage.com" which contains the HTML code 
`<a href="http://somepage.com/somepage">Click me</a>`, however the value of the "href" part could change at any time. I want to echo the same HTML code, but replace the `href` value with `http://mywebsite.com/somepage`. How can I do that? I have this so far

```
$q = htmlentities($_GET['q']);

$html2 = "https://somewebsite.com/search/" . str_replace(' ', '%20', $q);

$html = file_get_contents($html2);

echo $html;
```

---

I've seen [PHP DomDocument editing all links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469274/php-domdocument-editing-all-links), however this returns an error for me

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): I/O warning : failed to load
>   external entity

Comment: I'm aware of `str_replace`, but since I don't necessarily know the href value, I need some way of finding out the href value and changing it

Comment: tried `DOMDocument`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP DomDocument editing all links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469274/php-domdocument-editing-all-links)

Comment: Is $html the link ?

Comment: iainn Edited answer to explain

Comment: Try [Advanced HTML DOM](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom). It will let you parse the HTML and search for and replace what ever you want.

Comment: @Hugh did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace the searched term in the string like this:

```
<?php
// example page contents
$pageContents = '<a href="http://somepage.com/somepage">Click me</a>Some example text.
<div>Example div <a href="http://anotherDomain.com/somepage2">Another link</a>.</div>';

//  ------ the Search pattern explanation -------
// (http:\/\/)? means that the http:// may or may not exist
// ([\w]+) the parentheses () will remember the expression inside
// the \s? means there may or may not be a space character there

//  ------ the Replace pattern explanation -------
// replace the matched expression with the provided replacement
// the $2 is the second parenthesized expression () from the search pattern
$html = preg_replace('/<a href="(http:\/\/)?[\w.]+\/([\w]+)"\s?>/', '<a href="http://mywebsite.com/$2">' ,$pageContents);

echo $html;
?>
```

which outputs:

[Click me](http://mywebsite.com/somepage)Some example text.

Example div [Another link](http://mywebsite.com/somepage2).