# PHP Edit href to add server name for file_get_contents()

Tags: php, html

If i download a page using `file_get_contents()` and the result it's like this

```
<head>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta content="no-cache">
<link href="/style.css?q=245f90373d16694462b99d01a6a3eac8" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='/page?lang=en'></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/page?q=245f90373d16694462b99d01a6a3eac8"></a>
<a href="./page?q=245f90373d16694462b99d01a6a3eac8"></a>
<a href="http://example.com/page?q=245f90373d16694462b99d01a6a3eac8"></a>
<a href="https://example.com/page?q=245f90373d16694462b99d01a6a3eac8"></a>
</body>
[...]
</html>
```

I need a function that converts every `href` and `src` to `http://example2.org/*`

Note that there are quotes `"` but also `'`

A not difficult way to do it like `preg_replace()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace href with a different value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609568/replace-href-with-a-different-value)

Comment: @Muhammad Saquib Shaikh "Does this answer your question? Replace href with a different value" not completely. Mine it's a little more difficult.

Comment: Show your expected answer

Comment: @Muhammad Saquib Shaikh  Sorry but it's not my answer. I have double quote, single quote, can start with dot, without dot and could be src also that href

Comment: ```$html = preg_replace('/href=("|\')(.+)("|\')\s?/', 'href="http://mywebsite.com"' ,$pageContents);   $html = preg_replace('/src=("|\')(.+)("|\')\s?/', 'src="http://mywebsite.com"' ,$pageContents);    echo $html;```

Comment: @Muhammad Saquib Shaikh ```$html = preg_replace('/href=("|\')(.+)("|\')\s?/', 'href="http://mywebsite.com"' ,$pageContents);   $html = preg_replace('/src=("|\')(.+)("|\')\s?/', 'src="http://mywebsite.com"' ,$pageContents);    echo $html;``` destroys completely src replacing only ```http://mywebsite.com``` and also don't considers the link tag

Comment: I'm doing. When i finish to replace with http://yourwebsite.com I answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using Dom Parser it works and good.

It does not take the single quote `'` in

`<script type='text/javascript' src='/page?lang=en'></script>`

because it's an error, but the site it's not mine, so the answer it's

```
$html = str_get_html($yourpagecontent);
foreach($html->find('a[href]') as $element) {
        $tryer=$element->href;
        if ( substr($tryer, 0, strlen('/')) === '/') {
            $element->href = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME)."://".parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST).$tryer;
        }

        if ( substr($tryer, 0, strlen('./')) === './') {
            $element->href = dirname($url).substr($tryer, 1);
        }
}

foreach($html->find('link[href]') as $element) {
        $tryer=$element->href;
        if ( substr($tryer, 0, strlen('/')) === '/') {
            $element->href = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME)."://".parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST).$tryer;
        }
        
        if ( substr($tryer, 0, strlen('./')) === './') {
            $element->href = dirname($url).substr($tryer, 1);
        }  
}  

foreach($html->find('script[src]') as $element) {
        $tryer=$element->href;
        if ( substr($tryer, 0, strlen('/')) === '/') {
            $element->href = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME)."://".parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST).$tryer;
        }
        
        if ( substr($tryer, 0, strlen('./')) === './') {
            $element->href = dirname($url).substr($tryer, 1);
        }  
}
```