# Regex for getting links

Tags: regex

I want just to get the url of:

```
<a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">The linked text</a>
```

and I did a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/6UMbx5/1) but I don't understand why it does not work. I'd be interested to understand how to correct this.

```
href = "([^"])" [^>]* > ([^<]*)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4001362/3832970

Comment: On this question that you put the link is just the answer, I was more interested on an explanation.... If you please can explain then :)

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean), and the [explanation of your regex](https://regex101.com/r/jZMWeP/1). However, you wanted [this](https://regex101.com/r/jZMWeP/2)