# Extract links from HTML

Tags: php, dom

```
    <?php
    $cont = '<div class="video-image">
        <a href="video/TI - No+Matter+What/_CHheEQe9M8/" title="23">
            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/_CHheEQe9M8/3.jpg" alt="TI" width="130" height="78"/>
        </a>
        <span class="video-title"><a href="video/TI - No+Matter+What/_CHheEQe9M8/" title="sdg">No Matter What</a></span>
        <span class="video-artist"><a href="video/TI - No+Matter+What/_CHheEQe9M8/" title="ss" class="ellipsis">TI</a></span>
    </div>';

    if (preg_match_all('#<a href="([^>]*)"#iU', $cont, $arr))
    {
        foreach ($arr[1] as $value)
        {
            var_dump($value);
            $cont = preg_replace('#' . preg_quote($value, '#') . '#iU', 'http://site.com/' . $value, $cont);
        }
    }

    echo $cont;
```

Returned: `http://site.com/http://site.com/http://site.com/video/TI - No+Matter+What/_CHheEQe9M8/`

Why? I want : `http://site.com/video/TI - No+Matter+What/_CHheEQe9M8/`
How to do it? sorry for bad english

**EDIT**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($cont);
    foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node )
    {
        $cont = preg_replace('#' . preg_quote($node->getAttribute('href'), '#') . '#', "http://site.com/" . $node->getAttribute('href'), $cont);
    }    
    echo $cont;
```

This code returns `http://site.com/http://site.com/http://site.com/video/TI - No+Matter+What/_CHheEQe9M8/` too...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression for grabbing the href attribute of an A element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/regular-expression-for-grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Comment: @Gordon, I should not grab, but change

Comment: @Isis doesnt matter. same approach. dont make me fetch the duplicate for that :)

Comment: @Gordon, I have a problem with replacing links with DOMDocument...

Comment: @Isis [search if it has been answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=replace+href+dom+php) and if not make it into a question

Comment: *(hint)* you only want to prepend the href attribute with your string.

Comment: @Gordon, I did it. $node->setAttribute('href', "http://site.com/" . $node->getAttribute('href')); How to echo this? $dom->saveHTML(); is returned; with doctype/html/body

Comment: @Isis you seem to have a valid XHTML fragment there so try `$dom->loadXml($cont)` and `echo $dom->saveXml($dom->documentElement)` instead. If you just want to echo the href attributes, just do `echo $node->getAttribute('href')` after you changed them.

Comment: I just do echo all $cont.. sorry for bad english... echo $dom->saveXml($dom->documentElement); returned my $cont with <html><body>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadXml($xhtml);
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node )
{
    $node->setAttribute(
        'href', 
        "http://site.com/" . $node->getAttribute('href')
    );
}
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
```

Result:

```
<div class="video-image">
  <a href="http://site.com/video/TI - No+Matter+What/_CHheEQe9M8/" title="23">
    <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/_CHheEQe9M8/3.jpg" alt="TI" width="130" height="78"/>
  </a>
  <span class="video-title">
    <a href="http://site.com/video/TI - No+Matter+What/_CHheEQe9M8/" title="sdg">No Matter What</a>
  </span>
  <span class="video-artist">
    <a href="http://site.com/video/TI - No+Matter+What/_CHheEQe9M8/" title="ss" class="ellipsis">TI</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change ^> to ^" to start with as it picks to much as it is when I test it.