# Extract all urls Href php

Tags: php, dom, href

How do I convert these links to sha1? and then return to the html already applied with sha1

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    if (preg_match("/globo.com/i", $link->getAttribute('href'))) {
        $v = $link->getAttribute('href');
        $str = str_replace($v,'http://www.globo.com/?id='.sha1($v),$v);
        $str2 = str_replace($v,$str,$html);
        echo $str2."
";
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are trying to update an existing url with a new one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP preg_match regular expression problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286628/php-preg-match-regular-expression-problem)

Comment: Note that `preg_match('/something/i', $text)` is much slower than a simple `stripos($text, 'something') !== false`, which works completely fine in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the `href` back into the element:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($links as $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    if (preg_match("/globo.com/i", $href)) {
        $newHref = 'http://www.globo.com/?id=' . sha1($v);
        $link->setAttribute('href', $newHref);
    }
}
```

And then export the finished HTML using `saveHTML()`.

```
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```