# How to write a regex expression that replace anchors and links value

Tags: php, regex

My html code has many anchors and links such as :

```
<script src="/Common/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<link href="/Common/Css/UserAdmin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<a href="/test.php">test</a></li>
```

I want to change them into:

```
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/Common/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<link href="http://www.mydomain.com/Common/Css/UserAdmin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/test.php">test</a></li>
```

ie. add a `http://www.mydomain.com` before every src and href value, how to achieve this using regex expression. PS: I use PHP language.

Comment: why do you want to do that...? I guess you could add <base href="http://www.mydomain.com" /> inside your html's head tag..

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP preg_match regular expression problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286628/php-preg-match-regular-expression-problem)

Comment: This is either totally trivial (and the answers are that trivial as well), or you actually need to resolve relative links on client side against a base URI which would be somewhat interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regexp:

```
([\b]*)(src|href)([\b]*=[\b]*")(.+?")
```

and replace with:

```
\1\2\3http://www.mydomain.com\4
```

The main idea here is to use the lazy operator "+?"

```
Group1: ([\b]*)          0 or more blanks ... followed by 
Group2: (src|href)       src or href ... followed by 
Group3: ([\b]*=[\b]*")   0 or more blanks followed by = followed by 0 or more blanks followed by a quote ... followed by 
Group4: (.+?")           any group of characters until the nearest quote
```

then replace with what has matched Group1 then Group2 then Group3, insert http://www.mydomain.com, then what has matched Group4

Comment: `\b` is blank? I thought it matches a word-boundary position.

Answer (score 2):

Don't hurt yourself with regexp if you don't need to.

```
$search = array('<script src="/', '<link href="/', '<a href="/');
$d = 'http://www.mydomain.com';
$replace = array('<script src="'.$d.'/', '<link href="'.$d.'/', '<a href="'.$d.'/');
str_replace($search, $replace, $s)
```

Comment: No problem, mate. As long as your problem is solved it's fine with me ;)