# Use or avoid regexp?

Tags: php, regex

As programmer I need to filter, search and validate data every day. For all those problems I need to decide if I use a regular expression or plain php.

Even in a simple example like here I think it is not clear what to use:
[How to write a regex expression that replace anchors and links value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002376/how-to-write-a-regex-expression-that-replace-anchors-and-links-value/9002467#9002467)

The main advantage of using regexes is that is short but therefore you lose a lot of readability.

Is there an best practices way?

Comment: Ummm.....[regular expressions are a part of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php).

Comment: Depends entirely on the use case. Validating format is what regex is good for, parsing markup like HTML is not so good. Parsing language is also not good.

Comment: The question is *far* too vague to tell if regular expressions would be part of an optimal solution.

Comment: use all the tools that you can master, otherwise you'll start using the golden hammer (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can the input be expressed in a [regular grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar)? If so, use regular expression else you'll need to build a parser to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are a tool for matching patterns in text. Use them when you want to match patterns in text.

Comment: This is not precise. HTML markup could be called "patterns in text", but regular expressions cannot match them. Regex is only for matching *regular* languages.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the use case.

If, for example, you need to validate that a number is in the format `ddd.dddd--d`, a regular expression is best:

```
preg_match('/^\d{3}\.\d{4}--\d$/', $num);
```

But if you need to search for a string inside another, use string functions instead of regular expressions:

```
if (strpos("findme in here", "findme") !== FALSE) {

}
```

If you need to retrieve a substring based on its position rather than a variable context, use string functions:

```
$string = "This is the original";
$get = "is";
echo substr($string, strpos($string, $get) + strlen($get), strlen($string));
// the original
```

Answer (score 0):

Try first to use plain php (usually functions prefixed with str). If you cannot get a solution easily, then use regular expressions.