# PHP extract link from <a> tag

Tags: php, string, hyperlink, extract, href

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP String Manipulation: Extract hrefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702987/php-string-manipulation-extract-hrefs)

I am using php and have string with content =

`<a href="www.something.com">Click here</a>`

I need to get rid of everything except "www.something.com"
I assume this can be done with regular expressions.
Any help is appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: seems like everyone want to do this.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is very easy to do using SimpleXML:

```
$a = new SimpleXMLElement('<a href="www.something.com">Click here</a>');
echo $a['href']; // will echo www.something.com
```

Comment: One line solution `$url = (string)( new SimpleXMLElement('<a href="www.something.com">Click here</a>'))['href'];`

Answer (score 28):

Give this a whirl:

```
$link = '<a href="www.something.com">Click here</a>';
preg_match_all('/<a[^>]+href=([\'"])(?<href>.+?)\1[^>]*>/i', $link, $result);

if (!empty($result)) {
    # Found a link.
    echo $result['href'][0];
}
```

Result: `www.something.com`

Updated: Now requires the quoting style to match, addressing the comment below.

Comment: this can matches this: `href="_url_'` And that's wrong

Comment: not 100%. if you allow `'` then you should allow even no quote at all: `href=url`. Now stuff **gets harder**.

Comment: It does, with increased accuracy comes increased complexity. I'll leave it up to the OP to decide if what I've proposed is 'good enough' for his application. If you're going to go down the rabbit hole, read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: that link was where I wanted to bring you ^_^

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest following code for this:

```
$str = '<a href="www.something.com">Click here</a>';
preg_match('/href=(["\'])([^\1]*)\1/i', $str, $m);
echo $m[2] . "\n";
```

#### OUTPUT

```
www.something.com
```

This will take care of both single quote `'` and double quote `"` in the href link.

Comment: not at all because you wrote just `([^"]*)`

Comment: @yes123: Pls check now, I meant to use back reference `\1` there but in hurry typed `"`.

Comment: way better now. Also considering you needed the first parenthesis you could simplify it to `("|\')`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that is *ALWAYS* the format of the variable, below should do the trick. If the content may not be a link, this won't work. Essentially it looks for data enclosed within two quotations.

```
<?php

$string = '<a href="www.something.com">Click here</a>';

$pattern = '/"[a-zA-Z0-9.\/\-\?\&]*"/';

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: Yeah. As you can see, I'm a little rusty with my Regular Expressions ;)

Answer (score -1):

As probably you didn't meant your question that easy, but this does exactly what you're asking for:

```
$link = '<a href="www.something.com">Click here</a>';
$href = substr($link, 9, -16);
```

`$href` is:

```
string(17) "www.something.com"
```

As a regular expression it can be expressed it as this is:

```
$href = preg_match('(^<a href="([^"]*)">Click here</a>$)', $link, $matches) ? $matches[1] : die('Invalid input data.');
```

Is this helpful?

Comment: lol are you asking for a lots of -1? Note i didn't -1 you. You can check from my profile/reputation