# How to extract link and store as background-image

Tags: php, image, url, hyperlink

How can I extract the href- or src-link and store it as background-image?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365701/php-extract-link-from-a-tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have tried and what are you extracted from, but you can use jquery to extract attribute value like href

```
var val = $(ELEMENT).attr("href");
```

and than using jquery apply the value to element

```
$(Element).css({background-image:url(val)});
```

Comment: can't you see OP is asking a question about PHP??