# Getting href attribute

Tags: php

I have this php codes:

```
$main_url = "http://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/countries/DEN/summer/1896/";
$main_html=file_get_html($main_url);

$link = $main_html->getElementById('div_sports');

    foreach ($link->find('td') as $element){


        foreach($element->find('href') as $node){

        echo $node->item(0)->nodeValue . "\n";
        //$link_clean = $node->getAttribute('href');
        echo $link_clean . "\n";

        }

    }
```

If I print out $element, I get this output:

```
<td align="left" ><a href="/olympics/countries/DEN/summer/1896/ATH/">Athletics</a></td>
<td align="left" ><a href="/olympics/countries/DEN/summer/1896/FEN/">Fencing</a></td>
<td align="left" ><a href="/olympics/countries/DEN/summer/1896/GYM/">Gymnastics</a></td>
<td align="left" ><a href="/olympics/countries/DEN/summer/1896/SHO/">Shooting</a></td>
<td align="left" ><a href="/olympics/countries/DEN/summer/1896/WLT/">Weightlifting</a></td>
```

I need to extract this info:

/olympics/countries/DEN/summer/1896/ATH/
/olympics/countries/DEN/summer/1896/FEN/
..........

and so on. the code above is not working. CAn you helpme?

Comment: There are multiple questions about this on stackoverflow. Here are two:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702987/php-string-manipulation-extract-hrefs
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365701/php-extract-link-from-a-tag

Answer (score 2):

`href` is not a tag, it is a tag attribute.

So, you have to search for `<a>`:

```
foreach( $element->find('a') as $a)
{
    echo $a->href . "\n";
    (...)
}
```