# Find string in text and explode

Tags: php

I have a text:

```
$body = 'I lorem ipsum. And I have more text, I want explode this and search link: <a href="site.com/text/some">I link</a>.';
```

How can I find "I link" and explode `href`?

My code is:

```
if (strpos($body, 'site.com/') !== false) {
    $itemL = explode('/', $body);
}
```

But this not working.

Comment: what's the result of `var_dump($itemL)` after the `if`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP extract link from <a> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365701/php-extract-link-from-a-tag)

Comment: What do you want to explode? What is the output you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegEx is good choice here. Try:

```
$body = 'I lorem ipsum. And I have more text, I want explode this 
and search link: <a href="site.com/text/some">I link</a>.';

$reg_str='/<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>/';

preg_match_all($reg_str, $body, $matches);
echo $matches[1][0]."<br>";   //site.com/text/some
echo $matches[2][0];    //I link
```

**Update**

If you have a long text including many hrefs and many link text like `I link`, you could use for loop to output them, using code like:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($matches[1]);$i++){
   echo $matches[1][$i]; // echo all the hrefs
}

for($i=0; $i<count($matches[2]);$i++){
   echo $matches[2][$i]; // echo all the link texts.
}
```

If you want to replace the old href (e.g. `site.com/text/some`) with the new one (e.g. `site.com/some?id=32324`), you could try `preg_replace` like:

```
echo preg_replace('/<a(.*)href="(site.com\/text\/some)"(.*)>/','<a$1href="site.com/some?id=32324"$3>',$body);
```

Comment: But How I can in foreach paste $matches[1][0] ?

Comment: Thanks. I have 1 question. How I can replace `$body` with founded matches? Example: I want replace `site.com/text/some` on `site.com/some?id=32324` in text. How I can do it?

Comment: If you already know the old string, your'd better replace it directly using `str_replace`. If you don't know the exact old string, you could use `preg_replace` to find and replace the old string with the new one. However, you have to know the pattern of how to find the older string.

Comment: Updated. Hope it helps.

Comment: Do not parse HTML with regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/67332

Answer (score 1):

You could use DOM to operate through your html:

```php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($body);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//a') as $link) {
    var_dump($link->textContent);
    var_dump($link->getAttribute('href'));
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/942450)</kbd>

Comment: Caution should be taken that DOM approach will lose other HTML tags like `<span>` between `<a>` and `</a>`.

Comment: @Phil: it depends what does OP need. He can still get whole HTML of that link with this command in the loop: `$dom->saveXML($link)` and then parse that further...