# How to extract hrefs from HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, anchor, href

Assume I have a valid htmlfile which I save into a string. Now I want to extract the links of the anchor elements (hrefs). Therefore I want to use pure regular expressions.

```
preg_match_all('/<a [^>]*href="(.+)">/', $html, $match);
```

Usually I want to receive a string like that:

```
http://www.thisIsAHrefLinkIWantToHave.de
```

But instead I receive also the following string, logical caused by (.+) in the regex:

```
index?a=f">Link</a> &nbsp; <a href="index?a=ds">Link 2</a> &nbsp; <a href="index?b=b">Link 3</a> &nbsp; <a href="index?gf=d">Link 4</a> &nbsp; <a href="index?ttt=q">Link 5</a> &nbsp; <a href="index?g=my">Link 6</a> &nbsp; <a href="http://mysite.org
```

I found solutions like Xpath or DOMDocument (
[PHP String Manipulation: Extract hrefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702987/php-string-manipulation-extract-hrefs)) But I'd like to have solution without those/any libraries, just with regex. What I have to do to solve the matter of my regex?

I thought about from first " to next " . But how to create that pattern or another pattern, which solves the problem?

**[EDIT:]** *Solution*

```
preg_match_all('/<a [^>]*href="([A-Za-z0-9\/?=:&_.]+)?"/', $html, $match);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Musa is correct in that the period (.) is greedy. try [A-Za-z0-9_]+ instead of .+

Comment: That actually was the right hint I think. I added a few symbols '/<a [^>]*href="([A-Za-z0-9\/?=:&_.]+)?"/' . Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try  `preg_match_all('/<a [^>]*href="(.+)?">/', $html, $match);`, the `?` makes `.*` non-greedy.

Comment: Cause I see it as a requirement to do it without domdocument. That makes it too easy.