# Get all links with contain a word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre, scrape

I'm doing a script for get all the links from a website but I want to get only the links with a specific word. I have the following script and now I can get all the links and I don't know how to create a regx for search the word I want:

```
$url = file_get_contents("http://www.example.es");
preg_match_all("/<a(?:[^>]*)href=\"([^\"]*)\"(?:[^>]*)>(?:[^<]*)<\/a>/is", $url,    $todosenlaces);
```

Comment: this isalmost impossible to do correctly with regex - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702987/php-string-manipulation-extract-hrefs

Comment: Where this word should be? In anchor test or in url ?

Comment: I would advice you to use some library to do the heavy work. In this case you can go for the [symfony DomCrawler component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) + [symfony CssSelector component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html). They are meant to work together you can use jQuery like selectors in PHP, you just need to feed the DomCrawler with the string from the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean by specific word anchor text, you can use:

```
/<a.+href=["'](.*)["'].*>(.*(?:test|aa).*)<\/a>/isgmU
```

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tR6oQ2/3)**

In above example all anchors are found that have word `test` or `aa` in anchor text.

If you want only anchors with specific word inside anchor you could use:

```
/<a[^>]+href=["']([^>]*(?:test|aa)[^>]*)["'][^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/isgmU
```

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bM1lK0/2)**

However those won't work in all cases but for simple matching they should work.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.example.es");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$results = array();

$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
       $url = $tag->getAttribute('href');
       if (strpos($url,"apple") !== false){ //"apple" is the word to search for
           $results[] = $url;
       }

       //or search for the word in the hyperlink text 
       if (strpos($tag->nodeValue,"apple") !== false){
           $results[] = $url;
       }
}
```

`$results` will contain an array of all urls containing the word `apple`.

As birdpspider already pointed out it's not good to search links using a RegEx. The code parsing the document comes from: [PHP String Manipulation: Extract hrefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702987/php-string-manipulation-extract-hrefs).