# Regex: find link in html that does not contain square bracket with text eg. '[Some_Random_text]' but can contain empty square bracket '[]'

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Case 1:

Sample html : `<a href="https://www.jessussaveme.com/saveme/c-from.html?random[for_god_sake_save_me]=anyonethere&no=fr&lang=fr">Test</a>`

Expected output :

```
https://www.jessussaveme.com/saveme/c-from.html?random[for_god_sake_save_me]=anyonethere&no=fr&lang=fr
```

Case 2:

Sample html : `<a href="https://www.jessussaveme.com/saveme/c-from.html?random[]=anyonethere&no=fr&lang=fr">Test</a>`

Expected output: nothing. A link should not contain empty square brackets []

Case 3:

Sample html : `<a href="https://www.jessussaveme.com/saveme/c-from.html?random=anyonethere&no=fr&lang=fr">Test</a>`

Expected Output: `https://www.jessussaveme.com/saveme/c-from.html?random=anyonethere&no=fr&lang=fr`

**Which Links should be chosen:** 
1. Links that do contain not contain any square brackets '[]'
                          ***OR***
2. Links that contain non-empty square bracket '[Some_random_text]'

**Link That should not be picked:**
Links that contain an empty square bracket [].

Comment: RegEx is not suiteable for parsing HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/800214

Answer (score 0):

Rather than regex, you can use jQuery to do so:

```js
$("a").each(function(index) { // iterates all <a> elements
  console.log($(this).attr('href').includes('[]') ? '' : $(this).attr('href')); // check if contain "[]" or not.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.jessussaveme.com/saveme/c-from.html?reges[for_god_sake_save_me]=anyonethere&no=fr&lang=fr">Test</a>

<a href="https://www.jessussaveme.com/saveme/c-from.html?reges[]=anyonethere&no=fr&lang=fr">Test</a>

<a href="https://www.jessussaveme.com/saveme/c-from.html?random=anyonethere&no=fr&lang=fr">Test</a>
```

Unless you can fetch the text from `a href` [you shouldn't use regex to parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

---

Since you already said that you use PHP you could try the following [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703043/3654837) to extract URL:

```
$html = '<a href="https://www.jessussaveme.com/saveme/c-from.html?reges[for_god_sake_save_me]=anyonethere&no=fr&lang=fr">Test</a>

    <a href="https://www.jessussaveme.com/saveme/c-from.html?reges[]=anyonethere&no=fr&lang=fr">Test</a>

    <a href="https://www.jessussaveme.com/saveme/c-from.html?random=anyonethere&no=fr&lang=fr">Test</a>';

$hrefs = array();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
       $hrefs[] =  $tag->getAttribute('href');
}
```

And check if [contain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4366748/3654837) empty bracket:

```
foreach($hrefs as $a) 
{
    if (strpos($a, '[]') == false) {
        echo 'true'; // doesn't contain empty bracket
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this regex in backend with PHP.

Comment: @user9974829 You can use jQuery in PHP, though you need AJAX to communicate between the pages

Comment: Using ajax to parse in PHP will result in a significant slowdown compare to regex. will it not. ?

Comment: @user9974829 no. It's about the same.

Answer (score 0):

This one works :

`<\S.*?=\"(.*reges\[\w+\].*)\">.*>`

You can see it working here. It just matches the first tag in group 1 and returns nothing in the second scenario when the [ ] are empty.

https://regex101.com/r/cdvVnP/1

Edit:

For the third case, it should look something on the lines of :

```
if( !str.contains("reges[")){
  //passed() -pick up tat link as string doesnt contain reges[] or reges [some text]
}else{
//match with <\S.*?=\"(.*reges\[\w+\].*)\">.*>
// if you find match then pickup that link from group 1
}
```

Comment: @ Amey Shirke : 
 thanks for your reply. My mistake I did not describe case third.  A link that does not contain any square brackets should be passed. plz refer case 3 that I have just updated. Plz save me from this blood bath of regex.

Comment: for that, you can just do !str.contains("reges\[\w+\]") before you match using above regex

Comment: yes, that would work but 2 comparisons will be ineffective.   *reges: is just a random word.

Comment: updated the code.String.contains should be your keyword + [ for e.g : "reges["

Comment: Amey Shirke :  yes that will do the job but is there a way to avoid two comparison

Comment: As others have already mentioned that using regex for xml parsing may not be the best. As far as avoiding comparisons are concerned, I feel, this is the closest you can get.