# PHP preg_replace to replace img tags and move them within html text

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm developing a mobile web, which contents come from a foreign XML, and i'm having trouble with  tags. They're coming with style attributes, which I think would be easy to erase using preg_replace in php before showing the contents. The problem comes when a img tag is found within a text... something like: `"Hel<img .../>lo My name is Alfred<br/>"`. If I just erase the style attribute (generally coming with display:float), the image breaks the text, making it horrible to read.

**My solution is:** using preg_replace, I "clean" all image tags, BUT then I need to take those tags and place them after the next `<br/>`, `</p>`, etc. (every final of paragraph tag). I think it will at least make the page more readable and organized.

**The problem:** don't know how to get every img tag's index, just after I cleaned it, and then find the next end of paragraph to place it there.

Example-->

**before:**

```
Hell<img .../>o my name is Alfred.<br/>
<p>I come <img .../>from England</p>
```

**after:**

```
Hello my name is Alfred<br/>
<img .../>
<p>I come from England</p>
<img .../>
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT ---

**My doubt is:** if I found an img tag (`<img />`) in text (maybe using preg_replace, because I first needed to find a img tag, verify its attributes and change them if necessary), how do I get the index inside the whole string (by whole string I mean the whole html document read as a string) so I could take the whole tag and move it to the next end of paragraph?

Comment: Use `(.+?)` in place of `...` and you got yourself a regex. With a litte effort it's possible to find something in the many duplicates such as [php - Extracting from between two strings using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753092/php-extracting-from-between-two-strings-using-regex), albeit many regex answers have been botched lately.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, but with dots I didn't mean a regular expression. I was trying to say the image tag could have anything there (which actually doesn't really matter for my doubt). 
My doubt is: if I found an img tag (`<img />`) in text, how do I get the index inside the whole string so I could take the whole tag and move it to the next end of paragraph?

Comment: Are you replacing one paragraph at a time or the whole file?

Answer (score 0):

You won't get the position of the match from any preg_ function. On the other hand you can do the replacement with preg_replace_callback and pile up the matches to print them afterwards.
Example:

```
function noimages( $match )
{
  $stack = array();
  $img_regex = '%<img.*(/>|</img>)%ixU';
  $noimages = preg_replace_callback($img_regex, 
    function ($imgtag) use(&$stack) { array_push($stack, $imgtag[0]); return ''; },
    $match);
  return array($noimages,$stack);
}
```

So for example:

```
$match = '<p>I'm not <img src="yyy.jpg"/> interested on this <img src="zzz.jpg"></img> issue </p>';
list($withoutimg, $imgs) = noimages( $match );
```

Will return the block in $withoutimg and an array with the two img tags in $imgs.