# preg_replace : change all <img> tags link

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression for grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/regular-expression-for-grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

I wanna change all images link in a page

for example :

```
<a href="a.jpg"><img src="a.jpg" /></a>
```

to

```
<a href="mylink.html"><img src="a.jpg" /></a>
```

this is my code and not fully work

```
$page = preg_replace("!<a.*><img(.*)></a>!Ui",'<a href="'.$link.'">'."<img $1 border=\"0\" >".'</a>',$page);
```

Comment: duplicate of [Regular expression for grabbing the href attribute of an A element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/regular-expression-for-grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element) - the accepted answer contains everything you need to know to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing with Regex is [not a good idea](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html). If you need to manipulate (X)HTML, you should go with [DOM](http://php.net/DOM) and maybe [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). You can find an [example](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0081_parse_html_extract_data_from_html.html) on how to basically work with these [here](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0081_parse_html_extract_data_from_html.html).