# Very simple editing in a regular expression pattern

Tags: php, regex

How can I tranform this regex to search only in src=*** and not all the links that start with http and end with jpg, png, gif? Additionally I want to get the https images.
Thank you!

```
preg_match('!http://.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui' , $content , $matches);
```

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: And for the comedy value... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info but i didn't ask for this

Comment: @middaparka: It's more than comedy... it's truth

Comment: @Tomalak The best comedy is often based on the truth. :-)

Comment: @Tomalak it is comedy because apart from the funny rant, the answer is wrong. Regex can parse HTML. It's just not practical to do so in most cases when there is parsers readily available.

Comment: @Gordon: Regex _cannot_ parse HTML. Regex can parse strict, specific subsets of HTML; i.e. text strings that look like HTML because they are specific examples of HTML. Regex can parse stuff out of them.

Comment: @Tomalak http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491

Comment: @Gordon: o.O Perhaps, then, I should add "unless you go beyond the realm of sanity and write an illegible 90-line Perl script"

Comment: @Punkis see the accepted answer to [Regex for grabbing the href attribute of an a element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/regular-expression-for-grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element). I take you are smart enough to substitute a for img and href for src.

Comment: @Tomalak that's what I said right from the start: not practical ;)

Comment: @Gordon: OK then. I think for simplicity's sake I'll just continue telling people "don't do this" (even if not quite "you can't do this").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix your regex with a negative assertion to filter out the common occurences:

```
 (?<!src=["\']|src=)
```

"Prefixing" means after your `!` and before the `https?://..`

```
preg_match('!(?<!src=["\']|src=)http://.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui' , $content , $matches);
```

Comment: Hi there.
`preg_match_all('(?<!src=["\']|src=)', $content, $filtered);`
Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0

Comment: I'm not providing tutoring in the comments.

Comment: Yes I can. As counterperformance I request that you go over your /past/ questions, and utilize the ▲ upvote arrow on questions where additional help was provided in comments. Come back when you reached your vote limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, that catches only the src tag and select the image url:

```
<img[^>]+src\s*=\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>
```

Comment: Hello !
`$pattern = "<img[^>]+src\s*=\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>";`
`preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $filtered);`

I get this error : Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier ']'

Comment: @Punkis: You need to wrap the regex in delimiters.