# Get the content of the href attribute of an a element

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Hello,

I have the following html I want to parse:

```
<td align="left" nowrap="nowrap"><a href="XXXXXXX">
```

I want to save XXXXX on a variable.
I know next to nothing of regular expressions. I know how to do it using strpos, substr, etc. But I believe it is slower than using regex.

```
if (preg_match('!<td align="left" NOWRAP><a href=".\s+/.+">!', $result, $matches))
    echo $matches[1];
else
    echo "error!!!";
```

I know the previous code is an atrocity to a regex expert. But I really have no idea how to do it. I need *some* tips, not the full solution.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: After testing dom and regex, i've found out that using strpos, substr is actually faster...

Answer (score 3):

Here's my (not remotely original) tip: don't use regex to parse HTML. **Use an HTML parser.**

See [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html).

Comment: +1 for good advice 2 seconds earlier :D

Answer (score 2):

One thing of knowing regex is to know when *not* to use them.

Often when you want to *parse* HTML, 9/10 times, regex is not the right tool.

You can use a [DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Answer (score 1):

If your structure is *always* like the same you posted, you can use this REGEX:

```
<td\s+align="left"\s+nowrap="nowrap">\s*<a\s+href="(.*?")>
```

and then take the group #1 that is the string between parenthesis. You have to make a *group*, a zone between the parenthesis wich contains the data you would get. [This link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html) contains useful information about regex and the PHP implementation.

Comment: Thank you, but I get this error: "Unknown modifier '\' "

Comment: Try to escape the slash, like '\\'