# How to extract a href value

Tags: php, xml, regex

I would like to extract the href value (without any library), how can I do it?

```
<dm:link rel="uql" href="URL-URL-URL-URL" type="application/rss+xml"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything, or do you want the community to do your work for you?

Comment: I've tried with a php script but it takes a long time to execute.
I'm bad in Regex so I would like some help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though arguably a DOM parser would be the best solution, this small task could be done quite reliably with a regex.

Also, you'd need to import the info for the `dm` namespace if using a library.

```
preg_match('/\shref="(?<href>[^"]+)"/', $str, $match);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're usually better off parsing it using the likes of simplexml or dom libraries. Using a regex for this is bug-prone.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
(?<=href\=\")[\w:\-\=\/\:\d\?\.\#]*
```

should work

[image]

Comment: @Tom: I think it's problem with escaping the characters in the regex, because regex works fine as shown in the figure. Try it here yourself http://gskinner.com/RegExr/