# Why does my RegEx only end if I include some additional characters?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-match

Okay, let's say I'm trying to parse this:

```
href="http://google.com">Website</a>
```

This doesn't work:

```
preg_match('/href="http:\/\/(.+)">/', $a, $b);
```

But this does:

```
preg_match('/href="http:\/\/(.+)">Website/', $a, $b);
```

Why is this? The first one just keeps going to the end of the string.

Comment: it appears to work fine for me

Comment: @Dale: Probably because we're using different versions of RegEx or PHP or something. I'm working on a couple year old system.

Comment: do a `print_r($b);` after your preg_match and have you captured what you wanted?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950450/how-to-extract-a-href-value

Comment: The RegExp library has not changed so much. Most likely, you are not actually using `href="http://google.com">Website</a>` as haystack but a longer string that contains another set of double quotes.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: Yeah I simplified the question to get a quicker answer and make for easier reading. AD7six's answer fixed the problem though. Feel free to modify the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Greedy selector

The problem here is that your selector is greedy - it will match the longest possible string it can:

```
preg_match('/href="http:\/\/(.+)">/', $a, $b);
```

Since you use "any character" (`.`) it is matching right up until the very last occurrence of `">` that exists in the input string.

### None-greedy selector

If you make the selector none-greedy, then it will stop at the shortest possible match:

```
preg_match('/href="http:\/\/(.+?)">/', $a, $b);
```

Note the extra `?` in the regex pattern, which modifies the "one or more" (`+`) operator to be none greedy.

You can also make all selectors none-greedy by default by using the [`u` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
preg_match('/href="http:\/\/(.+)">/u', $a, $b);
```

Comment: Or you can change it for the whole expression: `/.../u`.

Answer (score 0):

this is the best href parser that i use test it

```
 preg_match("#href=[\"|']([^\"]*)[\"|']#",' '.$a.' ',$b);
```

Comment: What do the pound symbols mean instead of the forward slashes in preg_match?

Comment: Does not answer/explain the question. @JohnSmith - the first and last characters of a regex can be any character, a `#` is commonly used where a forward slash (which is the conventional character to use) forms part of the pattern - this way you don't need to escape them _in_ the pattern.

Comment: @JohnSmith They are just delimiters similar to the / you've used in your question, just another variant