# extract url using PHP

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

hi, i have this string in PHP

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="320" height="179" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xinpy5?width=320&wmode=transparent"></iframe><br /><a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xinpy5_le-buzz-pippa-middleton-agace-la-reine_news" target="_blank">Le buzz Pippa Middleton agace la Reine !</a> <i>par <a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/direct8" target="_blank">direct8</a></i>
```

i would like to extract the url from the anchor href attribute using preg_match or other php functins

Answer (score 3):

[Don't use regexes to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use the PHP DOM:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($str); // Your string

//get all anchors
$anchors = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');

//display all hrefs
for ($i = 0; $i < $anchors->length; $i++)
    echo $anchors->item($i)->getAttribute('href') . "<br />";
```

You can check if the node has a `href` using `hasAttribute()` first if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if (preg_match('#<a\s*[^>]*href="([^"]+)"#i', $string, $matches))
echo $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
(?<=href=\")[\w://\.\-]+
```