# fetching img tag, and it's src value

Tags: php, regex

I have 2 image tags, one after another

```
<img class="c1 c2 c3" title="Image Title 1" src="http://example.com/image-1.jpg" alt="" width="620" height="521"><img class="c1 c2 c3" title="Image Title 2" src="http://example.com/image-2.jpg" alt="" width="620" height="521">
```

I want a regular expression that can fetch 2 things:

- First 'img' tag
- 'src' value from first 'img' tag

How can I do it?

P.S. do someone know where I can test regular expression online

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expression to match the first **IMG** tag and its **src** value:

```
$subject = '<img class="c1 c2 c3" title="Image Title 1" src="http://example.com/image-1.jpg" alt="" width="620" height="521"><img class="c1 c2 c3" title="Image Title 2" src="http://example.com/image-2.jpg" alt="" width="620" height="521">';
preg_match('/<img\s.*?\bsrc="(.*?)".*?>/si', $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <img class="c1 c2 c3" title="Image Title 1" src="http://example.com/image-1.jpg" alt="" width="620" height="521">
    [1] => http://example.com/image-1.jpg
)
```

There are many tools to test regular expressions online. Here are just a few of them:

- http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/
- http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/

Comment: Thanks helped me alot! .* and .*? has differences :D

Answer (score 2):

Is there any special reason why you want to use a regular expression over more, generally, suitable tools like the [DOM extension](http://php.net/dom) ?

A basic example of getting the first `<img>`'s `src` attribute might look like:

```
$subject = '<img class="c1 c2 c3" title="Image Title 1" src="http://example.com/image-1.jpg" alt="" width="620" height="521"><img class="c1 c2 c3" title="Image Title 2" src="http://example.com/image-2.jpg" alt="" width="620" height="521">';
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($subject);
$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
// Echo first <img>'s src attribute if we found any <img>s
if ($imgs->length > 0) {
    echo $imgs->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: `preg_match('/<img [>]*src="([^"]*)"/i',$subject,$matches);`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `/(<img[^>]*)/` to get the first img tag(or any using backreference).
And then use something like `/src="([^"])/` to get src from tag string.

Answer to ps: http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/