# Creating a simple regex for scraping URLs

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

I'm trying to scrape a URL from the following string...

```
<a class="uf" href="--"><b>Massage</b> Sacramento. Mae's Acupressure</a>
```

Here's the regex I've got now...

```
<a class="uf" href="(.*?)">.*?<\/a>
```

However, it's not getting any results when scraping the page.

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm doing this in PHP, by the way.

Comment: Uh oh. Look out, people are gonna rip you apart for trying to parse URLs with regex... Use an actual parser somewhere.

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 1):

Actually your regex works just fine. You should provide more insight in what you try to accomplish

Try this:

```
$content = 'something <a class="uf" href="--"><b>Massage</b> Sacramento. Mae\'s Acupressure</a> some other text';
preg_match('#<a class="uf" href="(.*?)">.*?</a>#', $content, $matches);
print_r($matches);
exit;
```

It will print:

```
Array
(
  [0] => <a class="uf" href="--"><b>Massage</b> Sacramento. Mae's Acupressure</a>
  [1] => --
)
```

which is the expected result as far as I can see

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="uf" href="[A-Za-z_-\.]*?">[A-Za-z_-\.]*?<\/a>
```

Also can't forget:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)