# extract text from html using regex or other method

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

i am trying to extract the text "abcdef" from the following html using regex:

```
<a href="xyz.com" rel="bookmark" title="hello_world">abc def</a>
```

i am trying this pattern

```
$pattern = "<a href=(.*?) rel='bookmark' title=(.*?)>(.*?)</a>"
```

it would be helpful if anyone help me to figure out the pattern . I am using PHP .

thanks

Comment: If that's ALL your html, `strip_tags` will do the trick.
If not, `DOMDocument` is your friend. It's best to avoid regexps for parsing XML or HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead. Specifically, [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php). Your life will be much easier.

You *could* use a pattern like the following, but I really don't recommend using regexes to manipulate HTML:

```
/<a\s+href\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"\s+rel\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"\s+title\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"\s*>([^<]+)<\/a>/
```

I also noticed that in your regular expression you have `rel='bookmark'` whereas the original string has `rel="bookmark"`. This is probably why your original regex is not working.

Comment: here is the original html : http://laperuanavegana.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/   i just want this text "Flan de lúcuma" not from the title but from the body

Comment: @qmaruf Take a look at the `loadHTML` function and the `DOMDocument` object. This will give you all the information you need.