# Href URL matching,

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Im trying to match up in page source :

```
 <a href="/download/blahbal.html">
```

I have looked at one other link on this site and used the regex :

```
   '/<a href=["\']?(\/download\/[^"\'\s>]+)["\'\s>]?/i'
```

which returns all href links on the page but it misses off the .html on some links.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe the regex misses hrefs like this <a href="/download/here you have spaces">, anyways I suggest you to use a parser (DOMdocument) and retrieve all "a" tags with that.

Comment: "missing on some links" - can you give an example of where the .html was missing?

Comment: Use XPath `/html/body//a[@href=starts-with(., '/download')]`

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: thank you, so theres no way of using regular expressions for this?

Comment: @James there is ways to do that with regex but why do you want to do that with regex when its a piece of cake with XPath? XPath was invented to query XML documents specifically. Regex wasnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use the method [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element) to retrieve all hrefs, then you can use a regex or [strpos](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to "filter out" those who don't start with /download/.
The reason why you should use a parser instead of a regex is discussed in many other posts on stack overflow ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)). Once you parsed the document and got the hrefs you need, then you can filter them out with simple functions.

A little code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
//html string contains your html
$dom->loadHTML($html);
//at the end of the procedure this will be populated with filtered hrefs
$hrefs = array();
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node ) {
    //look for href attribute
    if( $node->hasAttribute( 'href' ) ) {
        $href = $node->getAttribute( 'href' );
        // filter out hrefs which don't start with /download/
        if( strpos( $href, "/download/" ) === 0 )
            $hrefs[] = $href; // store href
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested, works. strpos is easily subsistuted with a regex (preg_match) if necessary.

Comment: Thank you im still curious if you can do it with regex though.

Comment: It depends on which links are missing from the match, maybe the regex has just to be adjusted a little.

Comment: Yeah man i adjusted it and got it to work thank you :-) just facing another problem now but ill get there

Comment: I'm glad, but remember that regexes use to fail with some "unusual" hrefs attributes where DOM doesn't!

Comment: ah right thank you, do you know which method is faster ?

Comment: Never tested speed of the two methods, i'd bet regex can be faster but i can't swear it, maybe this can be a good point for a new post if there isn't already one opened. Usually performance difference is not so big to justify the loss of "precision" or functionalities.