# Regex matching for certain URLS

Tags: regex

I am writing a script that needs to pick out certain URLS on a page; these URLS, for example, can be `http://fiel.com/989898/etc.html` followed by `">load</a>`

How could I extract these using a regex ?

Comment: I get a "Page not found" message if I follow the link... :(

Comment: in what language? javascript? php?

Comment: @Jamesmiller Are you looking for the URLs on a page that are the targets of hyperlinks with the text "load"?

Comment: Oh its just an example of a link a fake one lol, its in php so the entrire url would be href="http://fiel.com/file/1631/shturm.rar">load</a>

Comment: and its in php i suck at regex its my biggest weakness when it comes to programming im getting better by doing though

Comment: to match URLS i have :

    '@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@' so ill need to add a part of ">load and im not sure how to

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript:

```
var links = document.links;
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
  if(links[i].match(/http\:\/\/fiel\.com/i)) 
  {
  }
}
```

in php

```
$html = '<html><body>....</body></html>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    if ($link->nodeValue == 'load') {
          $data = $link->getAttribute('href');
          //do whatever with href
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but there could be different links other than fiel.com which need matching ive noticed that each link follows ">load</a> so my regex needs to find a url followed by a ">load</a>