# how can i extract href from <a> tag using php

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Given link

```
$link="<a href='test.php'>test</a>";
```

How can i separate  href and anchor text using php.

Comment: "Separate" how? What do you want to do with the parts?

Answer (score 4):

```
$link = "<a href='test.php'>test</a>";
preg_match('~<a .*?href=[\'"]+(.*?)[\'"]+.*?>(.*?)</a>~ims', $link, $result);
//result[1] == test.php
//result[2] == test
```

or better one, if you want "test"

```
$link = "<a href='test.php'>test</a>";
$result = strip_tags($link);
```

eventually, you can look at [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: i have already tried it but it just gives me the anchor ttext..how will i get href

Comment: A lot of people whine about using regex for HTML and, in general, they're right to do so. However, if you _know_ that `$link` is _always_ going to be formatted the same way, then I don't see a problem personally. Just my 2¢. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$link="<a href='test.php'>test</a>";
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new domdocument;
$dom->loadHTML($link);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("a") as $a) {
    echo $a->textContent, "\n";
    echo $a->getAttribute("href"), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifically concrete about the string you'd like to parse, but a very easy way to do this with PHP is to parse it as a formatted string in your case ([Demo](http://codepad.org/uZR3oXsw)):

```
$link = "<a href='test.php'>test</a>";

$result = sscanf($link, "<a href='%[^']'>%[^<]</a>", $href, $text);

var_dump($result, $href, $text);
```

However this is not very stable if the format of the link changes, so you should better look for DomDocument which [has been already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444158/how-can-i-extract-href-from-a-tag-using-php/7444207#7444207).