# PHP regular expression for getting image source from anchor tag

Tags: php, regex

I need help to get the image source from image tab which is comprised into an anchor tag, e.g.

```
<p>this is sample text <a href="a link to some site"><img src="imagesource" height='x' width='y' /></a><p>
```

from above text string I want to retrieve the image source.

here is the actual description from which I have to extract the source for **first image tag only**

```
$desc = "<p></p><p><a href='http://somesitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/100_2666.JPG' title='100_2666.JPG'><img width=\"400\" src='http://somesitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/100_2666.JPG' alt='100_2666.JPG' /></a></p><p><a href='http://somesitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/100_2667.JPG' title='100_2667.JPG'><img width=\"400\" src='http://somesitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/100_2667.JPG' alt='100_2667.JPG' /></a></p><p>These are some of the variations of cotton floral prints used by the Knickerbocker Toy Co. in the 1960's. I constantly search for more examples of the unusual early prints and sometimes have to purchase a doll in fair condition just to have her dress!! See the article about the Knickerbocker Anns that follows.</p>";

$imgsrc_regex = '/<a (.*)><img.+?src=(\'|")(.+?)(\'|")[^>]*><(.*\/)*a>/';
preg_match($imgsrc_regex, $desc, $arr_match_array);
```

The above arr_match_array returns all anchor image tags where as I want to get only the first

Comment: Just give up. The <center> cannot hold - it is too late! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: What have you tried? (I think we can rule out using the search box.) -- And why does it have to be regex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: is it deliberate that the closing p is lacking the slash and the img src is written as scr? Do you want us to write you a complete HTML parser and a narrow AI to figure out your typo?

Comment: Hahaha!  I love you, tobyodavies....fantastic poetic reference (if you meant to do it :-P)

Comment: @Chris I can't claim credit - that line is in the answer (with 4 _thousand_ upvotes) that I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = <<<_A_
<p>this is sample text <a href="a link to some site"><img src="imagesource" height='x' width='y' /></a></p>
_A_;
$s = simplexml_load_string($x);
$images = $s->xpath('//img');
echo $images[0]['src'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/<\s*?img\s+[^>]*?\s*src\s*=\s*(["'])[[\\?+.]*?]\1[^>]*?>/
```

Although I would suggest you don't use regex, since HTML code may not be 100% compliant.  Try using an HTML parser like:

http://people.virginia.edu/~rtg2t/rda/ref.manual.html

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).