# preg_match for HTML 5 <time datetime="xxxx-xx-xx">

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How would I formulte the pattern so I would extract the XXXX-XX-XX out of a time tag?

The line I'm searching for in a $string is this:

```
<time datetime="XXXX-XXX-XX" itemprop="birth">
```

And I want to extract the part:

```
XXXX-XX-XX
```

I have this but it's not working:

```
preg_match('\<time datetime="d{4}-d{2}-d{2}"',$string,$date);
echo $date[0] . "<br />";
```

I find regex expressions so damn confusing ... any good tutorial recommendation would also be great! Appreciate your time and help.

Cheers

Comment: I think you'd be better off using PHP's methods of parsing XML on the file in question.

Comment: I would use an HTML/XML parser, find the element and just read the value of the `datetime` attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Comment: Regarding regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ is handy for quick testing of regexes.

Comment: PHP has a built-in XML parser, which is the best way to go. Your example (and those in the answers) will massively fail on `<time pubdate="pubdate" datetime=...` or `<time pubdate datetime=...`. It's not that difficult to parse it out, so why not save yourself some headaches. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `\d` in place of just `d`.

Also you need to enclose the regex in pair of delimiter.

Like:

```
preg_match('/\<time datetime="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"/',$string,$date);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: I'm getting an error of undefined offset 1 ... I think it's because sometimes I get the itemprop="birth" between <time and datetime=" ... what shall I do in this case?

Comment: Nevermind! Dumb question :) Got it working now! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the delimiters, some escapes and a capturing group:

```
preg_match('/<time datetime="(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})"/',$string,$date);
echo $date[1] . "<br />";
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems I wasn't that far from it and yet so far I was!

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern needs the /../

```
preg_match('/\<time datetime="d{4}-d{2}-d{2}"/',$string,$date);
```

Edit:
See tim's answer, you need the capture group too.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: @MichaelDillon Some of your recent edits are bad. Please stop doing this: `I would recommend http://www.pdfsharp.net/` => `I would recommend [this]`. Replacing the link text with the word `this` is a *bad edit*. At the very least, make it `I would recommend [PDF Sharp](http://...)`.

Comment: @MichaelDillon Your other edits are generally very welcome, fyi.

Comment: @meagar I admittedly got a little lazy ;)