# Extract HTML data using php/DOM

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

Im newbie with DOM so can someone tell me how to parse the following in php?

```
<div class="classname1">
    <div class="description">some description</div>

    <div class="classname2">
    <div class="classname3">some text 1</div>
    <div class="classname4">some text 2</div>
    <div class="classname6">some text 4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I would like to retrieve the text in the above class. There could be mode div before and after the html mentioned. I know I should create a dom

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();   
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);                
$divs = $xpath->query('//div[@class="classname1"]');    
foreach ($divs as $div) { 
    //...
}
```

I dont know how to access the classnames data

Comment: since you're looking for a single element, a better practice will be to use "id" instead of "class"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the getAttribute on the DOMElement 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php