# xml data upon attribute

Tags: php, xml

How can I get the value of the below xml on attribute name.

```
    <list version="1.0">
<meta>
<type>resource-list</type>
</meta>
<resources start="0" count="165">
<resource classname="Quote">
<field name="name">USD/KRW</field>
<field name="price">1131.319946</field>
<field name="symbol">KRW=X</field>
<field name="ts">1371547710</field>
<field name="type">currency</field>
<field name="volume">0</field>
</resource>
<resource classname="Quote">
<field name="name">SILVER 1 OZ 999 NY</field>
<field name="price">0.045962</field>
<field name="symbol">XAG=X</field>
<field name="ts">1371505422</field>
<field name="type">currency</field>
<field name="volume">7</field>
</resource>....
```

There are 165 such structures of

Want to fetch 
SILVER 1 OZ 999 NY
0.045962
XAG=X
1371505422 etc

My code so far goes like

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

foreach($xml->children() as $resources)
{
    foreach($resources->children() as $resource => $data)
    {
        echo $data->field['name'];
        echo "<br>";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the XML in the comment, it should be:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

foreach($xml->resources->resource as $resource)
{
    foreach($resource->field as $field)
    {
        echo $field->attributes()->name; // e.g. name, price, symbol
        echo (string)$field; // this is the content, e.g. SILVER 1 OZ 999 NY
    }
}
```

Note that `$xml` always contains the root element which in this case is `<list>`.

[Demo](http://codepad.org/nZ7q5Shw)

Comment: <list version="1.0">
<meta>
<type>resource-list</type>
</meta>
<resources start="0" count="165">
<resource classname="Quote">
<field name="name">USD/KRW</field>
<field name="price">1131.319946</field>
<field name="symbol">KRW=X</field>
<field name="ts">1371547710</field>
<field name="type">currency</field>
<field name="volume">0</field>
</resource>
<resource classname="Quote">
<field name="name">SILVER 1 OZ 999 NY</field>
<field name="price">0.045962</field>
<field name="symbol">XAG=X</field>
<field name="ts">1371505422</field>
<field name="type">currency</field>
.....

Comment: It gives me a blank output. Nothing displayed on screen! According to your modified code.

Comment: Yes its done. Thanks a ton. I was going crazy on it...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here you go.

```
foreach($xml->children() as $resources)
{
foreach($resources->children() as $resource => $data)
{
    echo $data->field['name'];

    echo "<br>";
    echo $resource->attributes()->name;

}


}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

corrected code:

```
<quote>
<name>test</name><price>567</price><symbol>xyz</symbol><ts>1371505422</ts>
<type>currency</type>
<volume>7</volume>
</quote>
$xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);
foreach ($xmlObject->children() as $node){
echo $node->Company;
echo $node->price;
echo $node->symbol;
echo $node->ts;
echo $node->type;
echo $node->volume;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not that far away. Query the elements by their name instead of using `children()`, you only need the `children()` method for children not within the elements namespace. In your code you just queried the wrong data, see this example ([Demo](https://eval.in/33892)):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

foreach($xml->resources->resource as $resource)
{
    echo "---------------\n";
    foreach($resource->field as $field)
    {
        echo $field['name'], ': ',  // e.g. name, price, symbol
             $field, "\n";          // this is the content, e.g. SILVER 1 OZ 999 NY
    }
}
```

Outout:

```
---------------
name: USD/KRW
price: 1131.319946
symbol: KRW=X
ts: 1371547710
type: currency
volume: 0
---------------
name: SILVER 1 OZ 999 NY
price: 0.045962
symbol: XAG=X
ts: 1371505422
type: currency
volume: 7
```

This is outlined and explained in the basic simplexml usage examples, see: http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic

Comment: What if I just want to extract the name and price? How should I go about.

Comment: see the linked examples, and also there is xpath to do that: [Xpath query with PHP (take two values)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293463/xpath-query-with-php-take-two-values/9293590#9293590)