# Using XMLDOM to retrieve data from youtube feeds

Tags: php, xml, youtube

I am using using PHP and XMLDOM to retrieve data about a youtube video. Retrieving data from the generic elements is fine such as: `<title></title>`. But I don't have any idea how to get the media namespace e.g: `<media:statistics viewCount="1234567" />`. How would I get the value of `viewCount`?

Here is my code:

```
/* Retrieve information for YouTube video */
$ytUser = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/".$user."/uploads?orderby=published&start-index=1&max-results=1"; 

// Read feed in to DOM
$doc = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'utf-8' );
$doc->load( $ytUser );
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
// Video Author 
$ytAuthor = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "name" )->item( 0 )->nodeValue;
// YT title 
$ytTitle = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "title" )->item( 0 )->nodeValue;
// YT description 
$des = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "description" )->item( 0 )->nodeValue;
$ytDescription = ( strlen( $des ) > 350 ) ? substr( $des, 0, 350 ) . '...' : $des;
```

Comment: It's just DOM, not XMLDOM. When you use any of the `load*` methods, the ctor arguments will get discarded, so you dont need them in your code. `preserveWhiteSpace` has to go before `load` and `formatOutput` after both. How to fetch elements with namespaces has been answered multiple times before but since `getElementsByTagName` gets by *local name*, you can simply get statistics anyway.

Comment: see http://codepad.viper-7.com/fhp5z3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grabbing the href attribute of an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/regular-expression-for-grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element/3820783#3820783)

Comment: I'm still receiving the error of `Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object`

Comment: then you are either not following along the lines of the example code I gave above because as you can see my example works or the feed of the user you are trying to fetch doesnt have a statistics element.

Comment: Thank you I got it working, just realised I had my variables named wrongly. Thanks for your help Gordon.

Comment: Also just curious why I got a vote down :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method `getElementsByTagNameNS`, like this:

```
$ns = 'the-complete-namespace-uri-for-media';
$media_statistics = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS( $ns , 'statistics' );
```

See the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not too sure what would go in the namespace uri. Could you give me an example? 
    `<yt:statistics favoriteCount='0' viewCount='1168'/>` 
This is the namespace but I wouldn't know the values of the two attributes as they will be generated depending on the video

Comment: The prefix `yt:` is not the actual namespace, but just an abbreviation. The actual one can be found as an attribute to the root element of the xml document. Look for the attribute `xmlns:yt="..."`.

Comment: I understand now, but I don't know how to get the value of viewCount. I have this so far: 
`$ns = "xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007";
$stats = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS( $ns , 'yt:statistics' );`

Comment: Once you have the element, use `getAttribute()` as usual, ie, `$stats->item(0)->getAttribute('viewCount')`.

Comment: If all the OP wants is getting the statistics element, s/he can use `getElementsByTagName` because that will only consider the local name, e.g. `getElementsByTagName('statistics')` will return the yt:statistics node. You only need `getElementsByTagNameNS` when you are looking for elements in a particular namespace.

Comment: When I try to use the getAttribute I get the error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object`

Comment: @Gordon I am trying to get the value of an attribute inside a namespace. For e.g: `<yt:statistics viewCount="123456" />`

Comment: @Jack I have added a working example to the comments below your question.