# Geting links from a context using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to grab all the links and their content from a text, but my problem is that the links might also have other attributes like class or id. What would be the pattern for this?

What i tried so far is:

```
/<a href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a\>/
```

Thank You,
Radu

Comment: There are quite a few posts on SO that advise against parsing html using regular expressions. You should load the html into some sort of a structure and walk through that structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/<a .*?href="(.*?)"[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>/i
```

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and see if you still want to use it.

Answer (score 3):

As the comment to your question states, avoid using regex for HTML. The **correct** way to do it is using `DOMDocument`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query('//*/a');

foreach ($links as $link) {
    /* do something with this */
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    $text = $link->nodeValue;
}
```

**Edit:**

[An even better answer on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)