# Get the href attribute in <a> Tag in plain text with embedded html tags

Tags: php, html, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

I have some plain text with some embeded html tags. Mainly

```
</br> <div> <p> <a> and <ul>.
```

I have removed then and replaced with new lines when appropriate with a combination of str_replace and strip_tags. Not very sophisticated but gets the job done for my need.

```
    $aux = str_replace(array("<br/>", "<li>", "</p>", "</div>"), array(PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL), $text);
    $aux = strip_tags($aux);
```

Now I would like to preserve the href attribute of `<a>` tags. I cannot use DOM parser as suggested here in this forum because the text is not valid html, just some tags in plain text.

Is there any function I can use or should I implement mine?

Comment: Just a note, the second argument of `str_replace` in this case can be just a single string.

Comment: and as you can see in the accepted answer, you can use DOM when you use `DOMDocument::loadHTML` which will use libxml's HTML Parser Module which can parse broken HTML.

Comment: "I cannot use DOM parser" -- prove it :) `$doc = new DOMDocument(); libxml_use_internal_errors(true); $doc->loadHTML('<a href="asd"><p></a>Test</p><li>'); echo $doc->saveHTML();`

Comment: I have read the post before I write mine but as I say I cannot use DOM, i'm not parsing an html document just plain text with some tags in it. Maybe regex is other option but yourself discourage about that.

Comment: @DavidCasillas: You can even load something that is not HTML but "only" has some HTML texts in it into DOMDocument. That's no problem at all.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I should be doing something wrong because i could not get the output i expect from the parser so I thought it couldn't parse not well formed html. Now I'm on the way. SO I must admit to Gordon that this is a duplicate question.