# Adding Image URL after displaying the Image in Wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am trying to display the URL of an Image after every image in the main content on Wordpress. To do this I am building a plugin.

If add the following code within my plugin I can display 2 of the same Image. as the code to display the image is stored in $1 below.

```
$content = preg_replace("/(<img([^>]*)>)/i",
    "<div class=\"image_wrap\">$1<div class=\"linkbox\">" .
    "$1</div></div>", $content );
```

In theory all I need to do is hack at the second instance of $1 in the above code to strip the image src. So below is the code I have tried and it using some substr and strpos functions but that doesn't seem to want to work for me.

```
$content = preg_replace("/(<img([^>]*)>)/i",
    "<div class=\"image_wrap\">$1<div class=\"linkbox\">" . 
     substr(substr("$1", strpos("$1","src=\"")+5), 0,strpos(substr("$1",strpos("$1","src=\"")+5),"\"")) .
</div></div>", $content );
```

Is there anything glaringly wrong with this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes there is, please see [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3820666/367456). Also it's not a real question you ask.

Comment: If you tried to evaluate those string patching expressions after the match, then you should have used them in a `preg_replace_callback` function. As you wrote it now, it gets executed before the `"$1"` is present.

Comment: @mario - cannot figure out the preg_replace_callback stuff. Do you have any relevant example code?

Comment: Figured it, posting solution back on here shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I eventually figured out thanks to Mario in the above comments

```
$content = preg_replace_callback(
        '/(<img([^>]*)>)/i',
        create_function(
            '$matches',
            'return CREDIT_HEAD . 
             "<div class=\"image_wrap\">$matches[0]<div class=\"linkbox\">" . 
                        substr(substr("$matches[0]", strpos("$matches[0]","src=\"")+5), 0,strpos(substr("$matches[0]", strpos("$matches[0]","src=\"")+5),"\"")) .
                    "</div></div>" . 
                    CREDIT_FOOT;'
        ),
        $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are examples for [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) in the manual. It usually goes like this:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback(
      "/(<img([^>]*)>)/i",
      "cb_image_wrap",
      $content
);

function cb_image_wrap($match) {

    list($all, $img, $attr) = $match;

    return
       "<div class=\"image_wrap\">$img<div class=\"linkbox\">" . 
       substr(substr("$img", strpos("$img","src=\"")+5), 0,
       strpos(substr("$img",strpos("$img","src=\"")+5),"\"")) .
       "</div></div>";
}
```

Your string patching code seems needlessly complicated.

It might also appropriate to look into [`HEREDOC`](http://php.net/HEREDOC)  strings.