# Regex to handle images

Tags: php, html, regex

How do I replace with text:

```
<img src="anyurl">
```

with:

```
<some extra html><img src="anyurl" alt=""></someextrahtml>
```

What is right regex to handle `<img src="*">`?

Comment: Does this really *have* to be regex? Couldn't you use an HTML parser instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Comment: @MarkByers which one, please give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/<img\s+src="(.*?)"\s+\/?>/
```

It'll grap the source of images.

**EDIT**

Here it is in PHP!

```
preg_match('/<img\s+src="(.*?)"\s+\/?>/', $target, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

So your src should be in `$matches[0];`

Comment: how to extract src of the image to variable?

Answer (score 2):

try this `/(<img.+src="[^"]"[^>]>)/si` but regex is not the preferred way to handle this. You should use DomDocument

Comment: how do I throw src of the image to separate variable?

Comment: You need to create a backreference with () so `/<img.+src="([^"])"[^>]>/si`

Comment: `preg_match('/<img.+src="([^"])"[^>]>/si', $html, $matches);`

Comment: foreach $matches as $match = each src?

Comment: Better to use a DOM Document if you're working with a DOM, but perhaps not if you're working with a fragment e.g. a comment etc.