# Regex and preg_match - get href for a with specific anchor text

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to get href for a link with specific anchor text, within an html page.

```
  </tr>
       <tr>
      <td><a href="/thisisafile.pdf" target="_blank" class="body1">
        This is some anchor text </a></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
```

I need to pull out /thisisafile.pdf, I have tried the following code:

```
preg_match('~<a.*href="(.*?)".?>.?This is some anchor text.?</a>~sm',$temp,$matches,0);
```

$temp contains the code above.

I have tried the regex in an online preg_match tester, and it matches. I have tried the regex in a regex tester without delimiter, and it works. But when I try it on my server (linux), I get 0 matches (not false).

Answer (score 1):

Possibly another duplicate. Check the first answer of this question. Regular expression engines tend to get clunky at times especially when you'd use the .* greedy pattern.

[Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
~<a.*href="(.*?)".?>.?This is some anchor text.?</a>~sm
```

into

```
~<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>.*?This is some anchor text.*?</a>~sm
```

You were missing the `*`. `.?` means that it only allows one or no characters. The `target="_blank" class="body1"` and the spaces before your text where therefore not allowed, causing your regular expression to fail.

**EDIT**: also made your first `.*` less greedy by replacing it with `.*?` to prevent future problems.