# Update specific XML node from attribute

Tags: php, xml, xmldom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

I have an xml chat script in which I add new chats via php. But at the same time I want to be able to update a specific users badge in the xml, but simply can't figure out how?

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
  <players>
    <player id="1">4</player>
    <player id="2">3</player>
  </players>
  <chats>
    <chat playerid="2">Some chat here...</chat>
    <chat playerid="1">skfgjh kjgh fdskgjhdf kgjhdf gkjd gkjdfhg dkfjhg</chat>
  </chats>
</data>
```

And here is the php in which I add a new chat:

```
$file = 'chat.xml';
$fp = fopen($file, "rb") or die("cannot open file");
$str = fread($fp, filesize($file));

$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-1");
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->loadXML($str) or die("Error");

$library = $xml->documentElement;

$message = $xml->createElement("chat","sdlkj oghdfiguh fdiugh eiuh eriu irgh eigu ekgjher");
$messageAttribute = $xml->createAttribute('playerid');
$messageAttribute->value = $opponent;
$message->appendChild($messageAttribute);

$library->childNodes->item(1)->appendChild($message);

echo "<xmp>". $xml->saveXML() ."</xmp>";
```

I have tried to add this but with no luck:

```
$xmlPath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$xmlNode = $xmlPath->query('//player[id="1"]');
```

I want to change the 4 to say 0.

Can somebody please help :-/

Comment: the example code in the linked dupe should give you all you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xmlNode = $xml->xpath('//player[@id = "1"]');
```

Comment: Oh yes... But how do I update this?

Comment: $xmlNode[0] = 0; maybe? or wrap the value in another tag $xmlNode[0]->score = 0;

Comment: Now I have tried this but with no luck:
`code`$library = $xml->documentElement;

$xmlPath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$xmlNode = $xmlPath->query('//player[@id="1"]');

$library->$xmlNode->replaceChild("0");