# extracting text from HTML

Tags: php, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

I'm trying to extract some folders names from HTML page, The source code of the HTML looks like this ..

```
<li><a href="/"> Parent Directory</a></li>
<li><a href=".ftpquota"> .ftpquota</a></li>
<li><a href="Folder%201/"> Folder 1/</a></li>
<li><a href="Floder%202/"> Folder 2/</a></li>
<li><a href="Folder%20N/"> Folder N/</a></li>
```

What I created so far, I can extract some folders, but not extracted correctly.

Here is what I've done ..

```
<?php

    $url = "URL";
    $page_data = file_get_contents($url);
    $search_pattern = "<li><a href=";
    $position = 0;

    while($position = strpos($page_data,$search_pattern, $position+strlen($search_pattern)))
    {
        //$pos2 = strpos($page_data, "\"> ", $position);
        //echo $position . " - " . $pos2 . " = " . ($pos2-$position) . "<br />";
        $str = substr($page_data,$position+strlen($search_pattern)+1, $pos2-$position);
        echo "<pre>" . $position . " || " . $str . "\n</pre>";
    }

?>
```

Each folder contains some files that I will copy using `copy()` since I'm using Windows, so I don't have `wget`.

What I'm doing wrong here??

This is my output:

```
156 || /"> Parent Directory
.ftpquota

Folder 1/

Folder 2/

Folder N/
```

But what I really need is:

```
Folder 1
Folder 2
Folder N
```

Cause later on, I'll loop through the folders and copy the files.

Comment: [simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: `print_r (explode(' ', strip_tags($string)))` will give you the array of all data between tags... where `$string` equals the input html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [DOMDocument](http://uk.php.net/DOMDOcument) and [DOMXPath](http://uk.php.net/DOMXPath) for `HTML`

```
$string = '<li><a href="/"> Parent Directory</a></li>
<li><a href=".ftpquota"> .ftpquota</a></li>
<li><a href="Folder%201/"> Folder 1/</a></li>
<li><a href="Floder%202/"> Folder 2/</a></li>
<li><a href="Folder%20N/"> Folder N/</a></li>
<li><a href="file.bin"> file.bin</a></li>';

$html = new DOMDocument(); 
$html->loadHTML($string);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
$filtered = $xpath->query("//a/@href");

foreach($filtered as $one){
    if(strlen($one->nodeValue) > 1) {
        echo urldecode($one->nodeValue)."\n";
    }
}
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/eeVbpAaj)

Comment: or you can use `$html->getElementsByTagName('a');`, right?

Comment: Maybe he wants just a part of the page and not all, he can use `DOMXPath` to search easier ..

Comment: :) yes, I saw `$search_pattern` and didn't read the rest :)

Comment: This code provided half of what I want, it just gets the folders, I also want the files .. As I said, there are files within the folders that I will retrieve later on.

Comment: just for clarification, extensions are not the same .. there are .bin, .pdf, .txt ,.tar .. multiple extensions.

Comment: my bad :( ... I'll try to be more precise :)

Comment: didn't work .. found this and it worked http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php#87294