# How to get the link text after a certain word from HTML tag?

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I am trying to get the text from the link that follows the text "Dir:", e.g. the text between the opening and closing of the "a" tag (name of the Director, here Sam Raimi) using php or regex.

For example

```
<span class="credit">
    Dir: <a href="/name/nm0000600/">Sam Raimi</a>
    With: <a href="/name/nm0001497/">Tobey Maguire</a>, <a href="/name/nm0000379/">Kirsten Dunst</a>, <a href="/name/nm0000353/">Willem Dafoe</a>
</span>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `^\s*Dir: .+?>([\w\s]+)</a>$`

Comment: Any chance you can help explain it a little more?

Comment: @Pogo There are cases where that won't work, and for the love of kittens, you can't parse html with regex.

Comment: Madara is correct, what you want to do is use one of the existing libraries to parse the HTML into a tree, then walk the tree and look for a text node that contains "Dir: " followed by an anchor node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Director in the Credits, you can use [XPath](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html):

```
//span[@class="credit"]/text()[contains(., "Dir:")]/following-sibling::a[1]'
```

This will get you the first a element following the text node containing the string "Dir:" which is child of a span element having a class attribute value of "credit"

See [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element) for a general usage example on how to work with DOM