# Get image url with preg_match

Tags: php, html, preg-match, image, src

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

I have to follow code:

```
   <div class="thumbinner" style="width:252px;"><img alt="" src="/images/thumb/0/03/HettyBlok.jpg/250px-HettyBlok.jpg" width="250" height="278" class="thumbimage" /></div>
```

Now i want to get the image url with preg_match.

But i don't know how to get this.

How can i get the image url?

Comment: preg_match('#src="(.*?)"#',$str,$match);... But generally dont use regex for this kind of thing, use a domparser.

Comment: I quote EJTH, a DomParser is more accurate, but it'd be a little slower...

Comment: A DOM parser would be a *lot* slower. There is nothing wrong with using a good RegExp for the above... You should only use DomParsing if you are going to use the produced tree in many different ways or searching for many complicated elements... otherwise it is a waste of resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '<div class="thumbinner" style="width:252px;"><img alt="" src="/images/thumb/0/03/HettyBlok.jpg/250px-HettyBlok.jpg" width="250" height="278" class="thumbimage" /></div>';
$url = preg_replace('#.*src="([^\"]+)".*#', '\1', $string);
```

Now you have your image url in `$url` var.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("#src=\"\(S\+)"#",$my_code,$my_link);
```

that should be ok

Answer (score 0):

You can also DOM parse as below

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<div class="thumbinner" style="width:252px;"><img alt="" src="/images/thumb/0/03/HettyBlok.jpg/250px-HettyBlok.jpg" width="250" height="278" class="thumbimage" /></div>');
$x = new DOMXPath($dom); 

foreach($x->query("//img") as $node) 
{
    echo $node->getAttribute("src");
}
```

Working Sample: http://codepad.org/szqI92Z8