# PHP script to extract specific href links

Tags: php, regex, extract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

I would like to make a php script that extracts all the href links from a webpage (mine) but only links with "/view/" in their string.

http://www.example.com/roger/that => not extracted

http://www.example.com/roger/view/that => extracted

And if possible all the links would be set in an array

So basically the script would be in my admin section and I would run it to get all the links containing the specific string '/view/'  in an array to use later in another script.

I've done my research and found this script but can't modify it to only include the specific links (with "/view/")

I know you guys are not my slaves so even if you have any tips for modifying the existing script I would be happy !

My script
http://pastebin.com/gYf9DZ8i

Thanks !

Comment: If you already managed to extract a list of *all* links, then just filter those. `$view_links = preg_grep('#/view/#', $matches[1]);`

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the page contents using **[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)**.

```
$input = file_get_contents("http://www.yourpage.php");
```

Then do a **[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)** to extract the set of links you want.

Regex:    `/\<a href(.*?\/view\/.*?)<\/a>/`

```
$pattern = '/\<a href(.*?\/view\/.*?)<\/a>/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

(**[Example](http://ideone.com/dOgGYh)**)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change this:

```
preg_match_all ("/a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s\"\']+".
                "(.*?)[\"\']+.*?>"."([^<]+|.*?)?<\/a>/",
                $var, &$matches);
```

into this

```
preg_match_all ("/<a.*href=\"([^\"]*\/view\/[^"]*)\"/", $var, &$matches);
```

Comment: The quotes inside the second regex needs to be escaped. This one will fire syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = file_get_contents("http://www.entendu.info");

preg_match_all ("/<a\s+[^>]*?\bhref\s*=\s*([\'\"])(?=[^\'\"]*\/view\/)(.*?)[\'\"]/", 
  $var, &$matches);    

$matches = $matches[2];

foreach($matches as $var)
{    
  print($var . "<br>\n");
}
```