# PHP Set-Cookie in the header for next request

Tags: php, curl, soap

I send a request to the server using php curl,i am getting the  server response like:

```
Array
(
 [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 [1] => Connection: close
 [2] => Date: Mon, 15 Jun 2015 10:34:22 GMT
 [3] => Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
 [4] => X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
 [5] => X-AspNet-Version: 1.1.4322
 [6] => Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=qqvn5y55p2cwqkmkdt5z1455; path=/
 [7] => Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
 [8] => Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 [9] => Content-Length: 1379
 )
```

In the next request i have to send this session ID for sending the XML.But i don't know how i can send that Session ID through header using CURL Method.

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name().'='.session_id());

OR

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);

Comment: Thanks Ramki..I am getting Response now..

Comment: You can adapt the code from this answer of mine, http://stackoverflow.com/a/13210186/1428679

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name().'='.session_id()); 

or



 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
```