# PHP/DOMDocument/Xpath - Failed to load DOM element from specific links

Tags: php, cookies, xpath, domdocument

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://www.sportsdirect.com/adidas-goletto-mens-astro-turf-trainers-263244?colcode=26324408";   
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    $name  = $xpath->query('//span[@id="ProductName"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo $name;

?>
```

With this code i have no problems. I am able to parse the link and get the name of the product. The problem comes when i try to parse other link. If i try to parse: http://www.sportsdirect.com/playboy-100ml-eau-de-toilette--754217?colcode=75421790

I get this error:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(http://www.sportsdirect.com/playboy-100ml-eau-de-toilette--754217?colcode=75421790): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in /public_html/test.php on line 5
```

I get this error because when i try to parse this link the website which i am parsing is checking my browser cookies and if i do not have cookie with name `ChosenSite` set to `www` it is redirecting me instantly to parse data from `http://bg.sportsdirect.com/playboy-100ml-eau-de-toilette--754217?colcode=75421790` which is unable to provide this data and from there i get the problem not getting the name.

So my question is:

**How can i set up cookies or can i use another method to parse this link ?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Either use [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210140/how-can-i-scrape-website-content-in-php-from-a-website-that-requires-a-cookie-lo) and analyze your data afterwards (that is, load the data from the curl response)
Or - if you're willing to spend some effort while learning another programming language (Python, that is) - have a look at [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) which has a built-in functionality for many many tasks connected with scraping in general.