# How to get sessionId and viewstate variables from this code?

Tags: php, html, regex, libcurl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

How can I extract the `sessionId` and `viewstate` variables from this code?

The code is this:

```php
$url = "http://www.atb.bergamo.it/ITA/Default.aspx?SEZ=2&PAG=38&MOD=LINTRV";

$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" />~',$html,$viewstate);

var_dump(file_get_contents($ckfile)); //<--- There's the sessionId variable in it
var_dump($viewstate[1]);              //<--- View State
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: It's easier to use a HTML parser to extract such values than a regex. For the regex however, this has been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this very simple without regex:

```
$viewstate = explode('id="__VIEWSTATE" value="', $html);
$viewstate = explode('"', $viewstate[1]);
$viewstate = $viewstate[0];
```

Same for the cookie:

```
$sesid = explode('SessionId', file_get_contents($ckfile));
$sesid = explode('\n', $sesid[1]);
$sesid = trim($sesid[0]);
```

Put it all together and you get

```
   $url = "http://www.atb.bergamo.it/ITA/Default.aspx?SEZ=2&PAG=38&MOD=LINTRV";    
   $ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
   $ch = curl_init ($url);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $html = curl_exec ($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

    $viewstate = explode('id="__VIEWSTATE" value="', $html);
    $viewstate = explode('"', $viewstate[1]);
    $viewstate = $viewstate[0];    

    $sesid = explode('_SessionId', file_get_contents($ckfile));
    $sesid = explode("\n", $sesid[1]);    
    $sesid = trim($sesid[0]);

    echo $viewstate."<br/>";
    echo $sesid;
```

Works on my test setup.