# Error when get src from first image using php?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
$content = 'I have a image <img border="0" alt="581.jpg - 58.03 KB" src="581.jpg">';
```

And php

```
preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+)[\'"].*>/i', $content, $image);
echo $image[0];
```

Result is: `581.jpg" border="0" alt="581.jpg -` , How to fix it ?

Comment: Hello is my answer solving your question ? and helpful for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Writing a regex for this is ... problematic to say the least. I would recommend using this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute('src') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Explanation:**

The reasons why you shouldn't use regex for what you want is that the markup for HTML varies. The position of the `src` attribute can differ, it may use single quotes instead of double quotes(some HTML attributes don't need quotes, for example this syntax is correct: `<img class=logo />`), it may be uppercase, and probably other issues I can't think of right now.

**Extra info:**

- [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)